# Want to copy .ebextensions (AWS Beanstalk) directory in repo into the root directory of a Java jar file using Gradle

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, jar, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot project, and I need to copy the .ebextensions folder from within my repo into the ROOT(top-level) folder of my jar file using Gradle. If it's not in the root directory of the jar file, I noticed that AWS Beanstalk will not pick up the nginx conf file under the .ebextensions folder.

i.e. this folder is currently here in the repo :

```
src
build.gradle
gradlew.bat
gradlew
build
README
.ebextensions
```

In my build.gradle, I have this code :

```
jar {
   from('.')
   into("./.")
   include '.ebextensions/**'
}
```

But, I find out that the .ebextensions folder will end up under BOOT-INF/classes/ in the jar file. And it will also wipe all other class files that would otherwise be under BOOT-INF/classes/ too!

How do I get my directory on the same level as BOOT-INF?   i.e. like this :

```
.
..
BOOT-INF
WEB-INF
.ebextensions
<Rest of the source files here>
```

Thanks!

P.S. I have also tried another solution below but it doesn't work either :

```
task copyEbExtensions(type: Copy) {
  from '.'
  into { getDestDir() }
  include '.ebextensions'
}
```

P.S.#2  Also, this is my build.gradle in case this is helpful :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {

   baseName = 'oneyearafter'
   version =  '0.1.26'
}



task copyEbExtensions(type: Copy) {
    from '.'
    into { getDestDir() }
    include '.ebextensions'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    // tag::tests[]

    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'


}


bootRun {
    addResources = true
}
```

Comment: Did you try to push that file under `/java/main/resources` folder? Gradle will copy all file under resources to root top of jar file.

Comment: Hi TuanBA, yes, I did try that initially. It is a Spring Boot project, and I originally had the .ebextensions folder under src/main/resources/ , but when the jar is built, I do not see the .ebextensions folder at all at the root level

Comment: I use custome gradle function to build jar file and it can copy files under `sources` to `root`. I cannot post all in comment so I will post in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my custom gradle function to build jar file. Run task `compileRunableJarFile` to compile jar file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude 'src/java/**/*'
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': title,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Implementation-Vendor': vendor,
                'Created-By': creator,
                'Main-Class': mainClass,
                'Manifest-Version': version,
                'Manifest-Title': title,
                'Application-Name': title,
                'JPA-PersistenceUnits': persistenceUnit
    }
}

//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task compileRunableJarFile(type: Jar, description: 'to create runable JAR.', group: 'compile') {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': title,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Implementation-Vendor': vendor,
                'Created-By': creator,
                'Main-Class': mainClass,
                'Manifest-Version': version,
                'Manifest-Title': title,
                'Application-Name': title,
                'JPA-PersistenceUnits': persistenceUnit
    }
    baseName = 'app_name_prefix-' + getCurrentTime()
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Hi Tuan, thanks for the answer, I will try to modify build.gradle based on what you posted to see if it works.  I also pasted my current build.gradle in my original question in case you are interested in it too